# Dealing with incorrect path in Xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, exception, try-catch

How do I check if the string given to Xpath parser is correct for a given XML?

Because if it isn't when I call

```
string temp = Convert.ToString(xmlNode.InnerText);
```

it will throw an error...

So far I do that. But it doesn't seem like a good way to do it...

```
public String GetString(String Xpath)
{
    string temp = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        XmlNode xmlNode = tempfile.SelectSingleNode(Xpath); //tempfile is an XML file in that class
        temp = Convert.ToString(xmlNode.InnerText);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: check if xmlNode == null before calling Convert.ToString(xmlNode.InnerText)

Comment: @prthrokz oh. it's that simple... thank you! :) You should make a proper answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SelectSingleNode(string Xpath)
```

returns null if it is not able to find a matching node in the xml tree.
There's also no reason to use Convert.ToString(xmlNode.InnerText), as xmlNode.InnerText is already a string.

```
if(xmlNode == null)
{
//something wrong with xpath
}
else
{
// do something with xmlNode.InnerText
....
}
```

Comment: The suggestion on dealing with the `null` value returned by `SelectSingleNode` is correct but as `xmlNode.InnerText` is of the .NET type `System.String` there is no need and no point in passing it to `Convert.ToString` so I would correct that as well and simply `return xmlNode.InnerText;` or do `temp = xmlNode.InnerText;`.

Comment: @Martin Honnen Nice catch :)